# Concatenate columns to one column with conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate all the columns of the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0987', 4, 'j'], ['9', 4, 'y'], ['9', 6, 't'], ['4', '', 'o'], ['', 9, 'o']],
                  columns=['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'])


In [1]:

  col_a col_b col_c
0  0987     4     j
1     9     4     y
2     9     6     t
3     4           u
4           9     o
```

Into one column with the added condition. The first is that all empty or null entries must be removed or not added to the new set. The second is that if the entry in the new column (col_new) comes from col_a or col_c it must have a label of 1. Otherwise it must be labelled 0.

So I would like the result to look like this:

```
col_new label
0  0987     1
1     9     1
2     9     1
3     4     1
4     4     0
5     4     0
6     6     0
7     9     0
8     j     1
9     y     1 
10    t     1
11    u     1
12    o     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), also for new label column use `rename` with lambda function and last filter rows by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = (df.rename(columns = lambda x: 1 if x in ['col_a','col_c'] else 0)
        .melt(var_name='label', value_name='col_new')
        .query('col_new != ""')[['col_new','label']])
print (df)

   col_new  label
0     0987      1
1        9      1
2        9      1
3        4      1
5        4      0
6        4      0
7        6      0
9        9      0
10       j      1
11       y      1
12       t      1
13       o      1
14       o      1
```

If there are missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0987', 4, 'j'], ['9', 4, 'y'], ['9', 6, 't'], 
                   ['4', np.nan, 'o'], [np.nan, 9, 'o']],
                  columns=['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'])


df = (df.rename(columns= lambda x: 1 if x in ['col_a','col_c'] else 0)
        .melt(var_name='label', value_name='col_new')
        .query('col_new == col_new')[['col_new','label']])
```

Or use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for filtering:

```
df = (df.rename(columns= lambda x: 1 if x in ['col_a','col_c'] else 0)
        .melt(var_name='label', value_name='col_new')[['col_new','label']])

df = df.dropna(subset=['col_new'])
```

---

```
print (df)

   col_new  label
0     0987      1
1        9      1
2        9      1
3        4      1
5        4      0
6        4      0
7        6      0
9        9      0
10       j      1
11       y      1
12       t      1
13       o      1
14       o      1
```